# when I display Score for an app everything fails

Tags: ios

This is my action:

```
-(void)Score{
    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + 1;
    ScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i",ScoreNumber];
}
```

Then when I run the app and I score 1 point, everything fails and the objects and images appear like were in the main.storyboard.

My intention is to see how score increases while you are playing.

Why does it happen and how can I find a solution? Thank you.

Comment: What does "everything fails" mean? Please clarify your issue.

Comment: It's the antithesis of the main song in the Lego movie.

Answer (score 0):

Is ScoreNumber a custom object you've created? You seem to be trying to cast it in the string as an `int`, so your code is probably failing in the second line.

If you want to keep a copy of the ScoreNumber to reference throughout your controller, create a property for an `NSInteger` in the interface of your implementation file and synthesize it:

```
@interface Class ()
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger scoreNumber;
@end

@implementation Class
@synthesize scoreNumber;
```